# jQuery .on() method is not working after dynamically creating a DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I make a button

```
var sectionbtn = document.createElement("button");
sectionbtn.className = "sections";
```

then right below, I have

```
$(document).on('click', '.sections', function() {
        console.log("clicked");
    });
```

but nothing is happening.

I have tried

```
$(mainbody).on('click', '.sections', function() {
        console.log("clicked");
    });
```

where mainbody is the parent of the .sections button.

I know there are other questions on this, but I have tried many different things and cannot seem to make it work. What is wrong with this?

Comment: Is button added in DOM ?

Comment: Its working here: https://jsfiddle.net/7kLLqrgp/

Comment: i think you have missed `document.body.appendChild(sectionbtn);`

Comment: You have to `append` it in DOM first before bind `click`

Comment: @ParthTrivedi sectionbtn is appended to a div that is in turn appended to document.body

Comment: where is your `mainbody`. Can you update code with append to div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd code this differently.  Since you're already using jQuery, I would use its tools instead, like so:

```
$('body')
  .append(
    $('<button>')
      .addClass('sections')
      .html('Click me')
  );
$('body').on('click', 'button.sections', function() {
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/7kLLqrgp/2/

I separated the click processor so you can process multiple sections.

Comment: But what if I have buttons with 'sections' class multiple places on the page and want to have one code that can trigger for all of them?

Comment: you can call dynamic created element event like this : 
$(document.body).on('click', 'button.sections', function() {
    alert('clicked');
});

Comment: @Annshuk, why would you use document.body instead of 'body'?  I would actually usually reference a div, not all the way out to the body tag.

Comment: @WilliamSchroederMcKinley, we don't really have any parent selector in provided question hence for demonstration, `$('body')` is just fine..

Comment: @OP, this could also be a way to bind events. To be extra specific. Try https://jsfiddle.net/7kLLqrgp/3/

Comment: @WilliamSchroederMcKinley, There should be no difference at all. $(document.body) is for much faster than body element but i think it's trivial ( you shouldn't worry about this, really ). :)

Comment: @Annshuk, In general, I'd expect the more specific the reference, the faster the query, but that's just my intuition.  This speed test says the 2 are pretty close:  https://jsperf.com/jquery-body-vs-document-body-selector .   But I can't speak to that myself.  All that said, I would generally prefer 'body' because it's more consistent with how I typically reference things.